# Laravel4 how to use a Facade as a Model observer?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Docs here: [Model Observers](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-observers)

What i want is to use a registered Facade as the observer. Docs states that you can

```
User::observe(new UserObserver);
```

What i want, instead, is to code something like, for example,

```
User::observe(Auth);
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your closest option would be to retrieve the underlying class the facade points to via `getFacadeRoot()`.

```
User::observe(Auth::getFacadeRoot());
```